# R read_yaml() reads a vector as parameter

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown

I would like to read a .yaml file to get yaml parameters for a Rmarkdown  report.
Original I have a yaml header to define a vector.

```
---
params:
  ids: !r c(2455, 2490) 
---
```

and it works, where `params$ids` is a vector.

However, if I put `ids: !r c(2455, 2490)` into a `report_params.yaml` file, and read that yaml file by

```
report_params <- yaml::read_yaml("report_params.yaml")
```

now `report_params$ids` is a string `'c(2455, 2490)'`.
so what did I miss, and how should I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The YAML default handler uses `!expr` rather than `!r`.

`report_params.yaml`:

```
---
params:
  ids: !expr c(2455, 2490)
---
```

```
yaml::read_yaml("report_params.yaml")
#> $params
#> $params$ids
#> [1] 2455 2490
```