# Accessing userid for a .yaml file

Tags: r, yaml, config

I'm using a .yaml file as my config file for some R code.  When I was the only R developer this didn't pose a problem, but now we're trying to bring multiple people on board.  We don't want to keep rewriting the config file because that's slow, and we don't want to create individual config files because we keep adding new elements to them so we'll likely end up running different code.

To access the .yaml file, I typically run the code below in R

```
config = yaml::read_yaml('base/config.yaml')
```

and the text in config.yaml starts with

```
experiments:
  # Config paths
  first: 'C:/Users/BNye/OneDrive/Science/experiments/first'
  second: 'C:/Users/BNye/OneDrive/Science/experiments/second'
  third: ...
```

and so on.  What I'd like to do is swap that out for something like

```
'C:/Users/{username}/OneDrive/Science/experiments/first'
```

and have it spit back `'C:/Users/BNye/OneDrive/Science/experiments/first'` when I run `config$experiments$first` in R, but that just returns the same line of text (`'C:/Users/{username}/OneDrive/Science/experiments/first'`) right back to me.  Using `setwd(paste0("C:/Users/",Sys.info()[6], "/OneDrive/Science/experiments"))`
in R worked fine, so the real hang up is config.  How should I code this?

Comment: On most systems `~` is an alias for your user home directory. Maybe try a path like '~/OneDrive/Science/experiments/first'. On Windows I think it defaults to your documents folder so you may have to go up a directory: '~/../OneDrive/Science/experiments/first'. You might also consider something like [the here package](https://here.r-lib.org/) to help with file paths.

Answer (score 1):

Using [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64454623/r-read-yaml-reads-a-vector-as-parameter) as a reference, I found a way to get R to parse the config file as an R expression.  My config files now read:

```
experiments:
  # Config paths
  first: !expr 'paste0("C:/Users/",Sys.info()[6], "/OneDrive/Science/experiments/first")'
  second: !expr 'paste0("C:/Users/",Sys.info()[6], "/OneDrive/Science/experiments/second")'
  third: ...
```

Then, when I read it in R, I use `config = yaml::read_yaml('base/config.yaml', eval.expr=TRUE)` and it works perfectly.  It feels like a fragile solution, but so far it's holding up.